# Define a type which is a string that starts with the key of another type definition?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a method on an object that can access storage by keys:

```
get<K extends keyof types.Storage> (key: K) {
    const keyParts = key.split('.');
    let storageDataObj = this.workingData; // Assign to a moving reference
    while (storageDataObj && keyParts.length > 1) {
        storageDataObj = storageDataObj[keyParts.shift()];
    }

    if (!storageDataObj) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return storageDataObj[key_parts.shift()];
    }
}

// types.ts
export type Storage {
   foo: FooObj;
   bar: BarObj;
}
```

This enforces that the string passed is of either type `'foo'` or `'bar'` but the method has the ability to take an arbitrarily nested key such as `'foo.x.y.z'` and break it down, traverse the tree and return `z`. Is there any way I can adapt the type of the `get` method to handle at least requirement that the primary key (`'foo'`) is present in the key string?

Comment: this might be dumb, but does it make sense to store it as `{foo: foo, x: x, y: y, z: z}` and give it a `toString()` or `display()` method?

Comment: Unfortunately this is coming legacy codebase, up until recently there has been no efforts to develop a schema for the models and until we migrate more of the codebase the keys below the top level are mostly undocumented, often being passed around, manipulated and stored as plain javascript objects.

Comment: Gotcha. I'm not sure the Typescript way of doing this, but something like Pattern Matching in Scala could handle this fairly easily, I'm sure someone has written something on how to do fake pattern matching in TS